# How does a linux kernel module know when its file has been opened?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, fopen, kernel-module

This is a newbie kernel module question... I have mymodule.c with a function:

```
static int mymodule_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    //printk(KERN_INFO "open called\n");
    /* Success */
    return 0;
}
```

and a user level program where the first line after variable initializations is:

```
FILE *pFile = fopen("/dev/mymodule", "r+");
```

When I run the user level program this `fopen` somehow calls the `mymodule_open` command in mymodule.c (compiled to mymodule.ko). How does it know to do this? I can't connect the dots as to how `mymodule_open()` knows when `fopen` opens up `/dev/mymodule`.

Comment: You linked `mymodule_open` with a `file_operations` structure, right? Connect the dots from there...

Comment: Read the very good [Linux Device Drivers](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000080.do). For your question specifically, see the section on [Major and Minor numbers](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch03.html#t2)

Comment: Something to note: The kernel maintains an open "refcount" for each device. If you do `xf1 = fopen("/dev/mymodule",...); xf2 = fopen("/dev/mymodule",...);` and then `fclose(xf2); fclose(xf1)`, your `mymodule_open` will _only_ be called for `xf1` and `mymodule_close` only for `xf1`. That is, no matter how many nested opens are done, the driver only gets a callback on the first one and only gets a close call on the last close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a module registration mechanism in kernel for device driver or kernel modules.

`/dev/module` will be linked with your module.

The Device operations and file operations structure is mapped with the device file.

something like

```
struct file_operations fops = {
open    : my_module_open,
release : my_module_release,
ioctl   : my_module_ioctl,
};
```

Device file will identify and open the module with help of major and minor number.First with device file and then file operations structure.

Also look into `device registration` and `device file operations`

Answer (score 2):

The moment user space hits **fopen** call, it gets routed to **open "system call"** and from there to the corresponding/registered **driver's fops-open** call **by identifying the major:minor number of the device file**.

Every Device file has got a "**major:minor**" tuple to belong to a particular driver, and corresponding fops structure will have the supported operations declared/defined.

> fopen(/dev/mymodule) -> library_function(open, file_arguments) ->
>   systemcall(open, file_arguments) -> filesystem_driver(inode, open,
>   more_arguments) -> filesystem_driver(major:minor, open,
>   more_arguments) -> fops_structure (open, more_arguments)

**NOTE: Above names are for explanation of flow of reach from fopen to mymodule_open, other than that, the names are not absolute function names, viz., library_function, systemcall, filesystem_driver...**

The driver knows about the /dev/mymodule file open, because it is a triggered event as mentioned in the above fashion, from fopen, each level of function starts triggering next level of function call, until reaches the ultimate function of mymodule_open inside driver